# how to create only one object in python every time the code runs

Tags: python, regex, function, class, object

Every time I run this code. The class Tracker creates a new object on every new line from the input text file. I want to only create one object when you first run the code and keep using that object throughout the whole input file and not create a new one everytime my class is called.

```
class Tracker(object):

    def __init__(self,region):
        self.region = region

    def make_tracker(self):
        self.region = re.search(r'CLI Command: \'show card detail\'',line)
        if self.region:
            print line
            self.region = "CPM OR IOM"
            return self.region
        end = re.search(r'(SUN|MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT)(.*)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d) UTC:$',line)
        if end:
            flag = "end"
            return flag

with open ('/home/thamer/SAMPLE.TXT','r') as f:
    for line in f:    
        first = Tracker(line)
        region = first.make_tracker()

        if region =="CPM or IOM":
            print "CPM or IOM"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your `with` statement to something like this:

```
with open ('/home/thamer/SAMPLE.TXT','r') as f:
    tracker = Tracker("")
    for line in f:    
        tracker.region = line
        region = tracker.make_tracker()

        if region =="CPM or IOM":
            print "CPM or IOM"
```

This way, you are changing `tracker.region` rather than `tracker` each time.